# google- app-engine maximum value

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am using google app engine and jdo for my application.I have a requirement to get the maximum long value of a datastore entity. is there a way to do this in app engine and jdo?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

JDOQL : "SELECT longField FROM mydomain.MyClass ORDER BY longField DESC RANGE 0,1"

Answer (score 0):

The AppEngine datastore supports the full range of `Long` values, so you can use `Long.MAX_VALUE` to acquire the maximum long value.  According to the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) This equates to `2^63 - 1`, which is equivalent to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

A list of all of the core types that AppEngine can support can be found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types).

Comment: What I wanted is to store a long value in a datastore table and get the maximum value of stored values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use following GQL query:

```
select *
from MyEntity
order by longField desc
limit 1
```

where `MyEntity` is your datastore entity that have field `longField` containing long values. It will return you 1 entity with largest value of `longField`

Comment: Sure but not part of JDO though

Comment: sorry, i got it. btw, it's just GQL